# what does 'deliver' mean in sport context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

within the following context:

"In a battle of big players, Kansas’ David McCormack delivered with 9 second-half points."

does deliver means to score?

Comment: Scoring was the result: McCormack [delivered²](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deliver) what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

It means he provided the performance that he was required to provide.  It might mean "scoring lots of points" or it might not, depending on the sport.

> In the World Cup, the French goalkeeper delivered, keeping a clean sheet throughout the group stage and only allowing three goals in the whole tournament.

It means that the French goal did what he was required to do.  He stopped the other teams from scoring.

Similarly in your example Kansas needed McCormack to score lots of points.  He did.  He delivered.

Answer (score 0):

It is not confined to sport.

"To deliver", metaphorically, means something like "to fulfil a promise" or "provide what was needed".

So, in this context, "McCormack delivered" means, "McCormack provided what was needed", which was scoring points.